# How do I get a .p12 certificate and a .mobileprovision file to export for iOS in CS5.5?

Tags: ios, certificate, flash-cs5

I've been looking into developing applications for iOS using Flash CS5.5, however I'm having some trouble publishing the application because I don't know where I can get a signed certificate. CS4 had a feature when exporting for AIR that let you create one on the spot but this doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Any suggestions on where to get these files so I can try this feature out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a signed certificate for iOS application production requires registration as an iOS developer with apple. Then you get your signing certificate and provisioning profiles.

Comment: Eh, just did that. Drained $120 out of me for it to :/